# Extract specific stocks based on their price from Quant Mod in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm running quantmod and I want to read in a list of stocks and their prices as of a certain date. I then want to keep those stocks that meet a specific threshold.

My code starts:

```
library(quantmod)
s = c("AAPL","FB","GOOG", "CRM")
e = new.env() #environment in which to store data
getSymbols(s, src="yahoo", env=e)
prices = do.call(merge, eapply(e, Cl)[s])

today = prices["2017-04-07",]  
today

The output is:

   AAPL.Close FB.Close GOOG.Close CRM.Close
2017-04-07     143.34   140.78     824.67     84.38
```

I want to keep only those with a price >140 so it should read:

```
   AAPL.Close GOOG.Close
2017-04-07     143.34     824.67
```

Comment: Try this: `threshold = 140, filteredPx =  today[,today > threshold ]`

Answer (score 0):

You already have prices as of a certain date in `today`. So you just need to subset `today` by the columns with a close price > 140.  You can do that by subsetting the columns with a logical vector.

```
R> today[, today > 140]
           AAPL.Close FB.Close GOOG.Close
2017-04-07     143.34   140.78     824.67
```